# Adding digital certification to WPF application

Tags: wpf, digital-certificate

I have a digital certificate(*.pfx and it is from verisign) for my application which provided by our client. I don't know how will I make a use of it.

I have already had a Temporary.pfx file and I thought replacing that file should work.. However it is not happening.

Can anybody tell me how to use the Certificate.pfx file for the WPF application.